# Why do some domains ban me when using local proxy server?

Tags: html, delphi, networking, web

I'm working on a web filter that uses a local proxy. I'm using indy to do all the work but when I'm testing, occasionally a website will block me. Why would this be? And if the proxy is local, surely all the website would see is my networks IP; how would they know?

Unless this is something unrelated completely like multiple connections to the site throwing up a flag which causes a ban?

Thanks

Comment: Web servers won't block you based on whether or not you are using Indy components, nor Delphi.  This isn't really a programming question.  Perhaps ServerFault or SuperUser SE?

Comment: it doesn't seem like you have enough info to make a determination. many sites do block public relay proxies, simply because they think that anyone using a proxy must be up to no good, and from a security perspective, they are not wrong to think down that path, but it is darned inconvenient.